# Proving the Inverse Function Theorem from the Implicit function theorem for general normed vector spaces

Tags: analysis

I have seen a proof of this for  $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, but I was wondering what the proof looked like if we are in general normed vector spaces.

Comment: You'll need something more, for instance a norm...

Comment: I'd taken that as a given (i.e. when I said general vector space, i meant normed, since those are the only kind of spaces that you can apply either IFT to)

Comment: Once you have the correct assumptions, why should the proof look any different?

Comment: I don't know, I wondered if an infinite dimensional case may lead to some problems